# Social.framework Facebook possibilities

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I can't find easy answers on the web. I know that `Social.framework` is great for making things less complicated and less buggy. However I tried to implement `like` and failed - I don't think it is possible using only `Social.framework`. Now I'm trying to get some posts image and add a `comment` to it, it's also complicated, I'm not sure if possible. It seems all more complicated stuff you used to do via opengraph isn't possible with `Social.framework`.

Maybe there is a way to mix `Social.framework` with `FacebookSDK` and log user via the first framework and get object via 2nd with opengraph?

Can anyone write if these actions are possible? Or how to know what is possible/impossible with `Social.framework`? I consider mainly Facebook.

-- edit --

An example would be:

```
NSURL *likeUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me/og.likes"];
NSURL *objectUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"object_with_tags_to_like"];
NSDictionary *parameters = @{ACFacebookAppIdKey: @"111",
                             @"object": objectUrl};
SLRequest *facebookRequest = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook 
                                        requestMethod:SLRequestMethodPOST 
                                        URL:likeUrl 
                                        parameters:parameters];
facebookRequest.account = facebookAccount;

[facebookRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
    // set a breakpoint here, we're getting in resp: 
    // "Www-Authenticate" = "OAuth \"Facebook Platform\" \"invalid_request\" \
    // "The action you're trying to publish is invalid because it does not specify any reference objects. 
    // At least one of the following properties must be specified: object.\"";
}];
```

Here we can see that passing object isn't easy. With FacebookSDK you'd simply:

```
NSMutableDictionary<FBGraphObject> *action = [FBGraphObject graphObject];
action[@"object"] = urlAddress;
[FBRequestConnection startForPostWithGraphPath:@"me/og.likes" 
                     graphObject:action 
                     completionHandler:nil];
```

But here you can't create FBGraphObject. What to use instead?

Answer (score 1):

Honestly the Facebook SDK is quit powerful and simple to use. It allows you much more functionality in terms of Liking and Commenting so I would recommend you move towards that. The SocialFramework is limited, it is mainly used for sending a quick post (using their template, -> no customization) and quick login.

I have successfully done all of what you are asking for using solely the Facebook SDK.

Comment: I've also did it using only FacebookSDK, it's quite easy. I'm using FacebookSDK from 1year or so, so I'm really tired of its bugs. Ofc Social.framework is based on FacebookSDK but they'll be fixing everything as soon as possible, and we won't have to trouble ourselves with updating all apps. Anyway I'm asking about Social.framework because this is also possible to do via Social.framework - why shouldn't I know how to do it via this library? It's better to know more solutions than to know only one possibility.